# Spring Controller unit test best practices

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

In my application I have a controller based on a given pattern:

```
public class Controller {

@Autowired
Mapper mapper;

@Autowired
Service service;

public EntityDto create(EntityDto dto) {
    Entity entity = mapper.mapToEntity(dto);
    Entity saved = service.save(entity);
    return mapper.mapToDto(saved);
}
```

What is a good approach to test classes like that? I see a few possibilities:

1. mock everything with Mockito and check if an object retrieved from one mock is passed to another
2. do integration tests with a Spring context running
3. skip Controller's test since it contains no business logic

Is any of above ones OK? Maybe some other way?

Comment: 1 and 2 together.

Comment: You got some answers, are none of them good enough? Please elaborate on the question. For example, your controller should have annotations like GetMapping, RestController etc. Regarding your options: 1. Mock the service, but not the mapper (should have its own unittest) & 2 Always have one test verifying a valid Spring Context. 3. The Spring team created MockMvc for a reason, to test controllers. I recommend using it

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Spring boot application ,you can write your test class under test package as follows :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class TestController {

@Autowired
Controller controller;

@Test
public void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testGroupAlert() throws EntityNotFoundException, Exception {

    Entitydto dto = new Entitydto() //Initialize your Entitydto object
    controller.create(dto);
}
```

Comment: But this is actually kind of a integration test rather than unit..?

Comment: If you really want to unit test, why do you use field injection ?

Comment: how its related?:)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've seen most frequently is the following:

- The developer who creates the controller creates unit tests using
  mocks.
- A QA team creates integration tests with a Spring context (and a tool
  like [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/)).

Comment: I also see this often, but IMO this approach is coupled too much with production code. In this case its not possible to make a refactoring without breaking tests, and AFAIK it is one of the main goals of unit testing. With this approach tests will not support refactoring, because every changed line of code will break the tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do great tests the only way is to do Unit Tests AND Integration Tests.

Integration Tests are launched only when needed (e.g : Maven can identifie wether the test is an integration one or not).

And Unit Tests can't be replaced by anything if you want resilient code.

A good way to do this is, as you guessed to use mock engines. (Like Mockito).

The purpose to this is to really control the class in every way possible, without the interaction of other layers.

But BEWARE ! This works if you do this on ALL layers and all classes.

If you're working on existing code, look at what is done and try to work with it and do your best.

And remember, that a good test is not the one that cover the most, it's the one that cover the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller doesn't have business logic, but it accepts and produces some JSON (or other data), which will be used by other services (i.e. frontend).

That's why it worth to check an API contract.

For this purpose, you can use [Spring Could Contract](http://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract) framework.

Answer (score 0):

> mock everything with Mockito and check if an object retrieved from one mock is passed to another

Typically you extract logic into methods that explain what they do. If the method uses a result of another method call, then I would mock that method call and make it return a fixed value.

> do integration tests with a Spring context running

You should certainly have a test that validates your spring context (you may only need one)

> skip Controller's test since it contains no business log

Your controller should not contain business logic, but rather delegate to a service that does some work. Spring has MockMvc which let you test one controller at a time (and mock other beans in the spring context). This provides many opportunities for some interesting and useful tests.

-

I prefer to mock out external systems. I  like to test the controller and the logic in the service. Using MockMvc I can also validate the http response.

Let's say I have a three layered application:
`Controller -> Service -> Repository (mock this one)`

Example-test with MockMvc:

```
 @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
 @WebMvcTest(controllers = {CategoryController.class})
 public class CategoryControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private CategoryRepository repository; // mock database, but validate logic in the service-class

  @Test
  public void create_new_catgory() throws Exception {

    var category = new Category("test");
    given(repository.save(any())).willReturn(category);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/category")
            .content(toJson(new CategoryRequestDto("")))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(content().json(toJson(category)));

    verify(repository, times(1)).save(any());
  }
}
```

Example on a test which is more of an integration test (running an in-mem database):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
classes = {ShoprApplication.class, TestConfig.class})
@Transactional
public class ProductControllerTest {

  @Autowired TestRestTemplate template;
  @Autowired EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
  private TestEntityManager em;

  @BeforeEach
  public void configure() {
    em = new TestEntityManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }

  @Test
  public void createProduct() {
    var response = template.postForEntity(
            "/product",
            new Product("Apples", 15.00, new Category("Fruit"), 6),
            Long.class);

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
    assertTrue(response.getBody() != null && response.getBody().intValue() > 0L);

    var product = em.getEntityManager().find(Product.class, response.getBody());
    assertNotNull(product);
    assertEquals("Apples", product.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2

I think you should test all classes with the mocking library in the all layers. Even the most trivial classes is good to test.

Then you should have the integration tests.

I think the integration tests can also be run all the time if they don't require any external systems working. Only thing can be time. I haven't been in the projects where some minutes wait for the integration tests would be too much.

The in memory databases and integration test libraries/frameworks (for example @SpringBootTest) are good for the integration tests.

I think good tests make it possible to do a lot of refactoring. The integration tests don't break so much if you do the refactoring. The JUnit tests may break, but I don't think so it's problem. You should always have as simple and clean code and tests as possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move most of the domain logic to the model (you may want to check out a book on DDD)
2. Cover domain model with unit tests. Thus most of the tests stay on unit level and they don't need mocking.
3. For each piece of functionality write just a few high-level tests - they will check that serialization, AOP, URL mapping is done correctly and everything works from head to toe. You can use MockMvc for this.

You wind up with a [Test Pyramid](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html) - lots of fast unit tests, not as many high-level tests that check it all together, no mocking frameworks.